# Appium Webdriver.Remote not accepting desired capabilities

Tags: python-3.x, webdriver, appium

I am attempting to practice Appium automation with Python. I have the following code:

```
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '17.0'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone 15 Pro'
desired_caps['udid'] = 'dummy_udid_here'
desired_caps['bundleId'] = 'com.dummyname.IntegrationApp'

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

However, there is an error with passing in desired caps to driver, saying `Expected type 'bool', got 'dict[str, str]' instead.`

I have tried changing the way I defined desired_caps, including a dictionary literal. I have also tried initializing the webdriver in another file. I am expecting the webdriver.Remote to accept the desired_caps as is, but I cannot figure out why I am getting this variable type error.

I am on a working branch that also includes the initialization local and Jenkins Chrome webdrivers.

I am not sure if something has changed since Appium 2 with this webdriver.Remote, or if it is something with using Appium Python Client 3.0.0.